# knife winrm to windows machine fails with Connection Refused

Tags: window, chef-infra, knife, winrm

I am trying to use knife to bootstrap a windows machine.
When running the command 'knife bootstrap windows winrm' i receive the following error:

```
ERROR: Network Error: Connection refused - connect(2) (http://<server>:5985)
```

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Open firewall port 5985 on your windows node. This port is used by WS-management. Click [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13178.fsrm-port-5985-must-be-allowed-through-the-windows-firewall-for-access-denied-assistance.aspx#Resolution) to find out how to enable this port